# Struts 2 - Tiles-Result with HTML Anchor

Tags: struts2, anchor, tiles

is it somehow possible to add an anchor (or hash) to a Struts 2 Action-URL? To be specific:

I have a html form which can be extended with more fields if the user clicks a button "add more fields". This Button sends a html submit to the backend (Action "thismyaction") where a list object is filled with another set of input fields. The action then returns to a tile "thisismyform" which loads the same jsp as before, where the new fieldset is visible.

(Unfortunately there is no way to achieve that via ajax / JS in this project at the time. I know that you usually add fields that way, but i got the project as it is.)

Each fieldset is counted (fieldset-0, if user adds more fields another set is added "fieldset-1"). The sets always contain the same fields, but enumerated.

What happens here? There is a post to the action which generates another fieldset and redirects back to the same page, where it renders all fieldsets. Important: the result type is "tiles"! I guess this is what makes it difficult.

Now I want to dynamically add an anchor to this URL "thisismyaction.do", like e.g. "thisismyaction.do#fieldset-1". Use Case: User adds another fieldset, post to the action => result type="tiles" => JSP, user sees reload of the page with the new, second fieldset and gets "scrolled" to the second fieldset via the anchor. Is that possible?

I hope I could describe it properly, what I want to achieve... If there are questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want. Both the `<s:url>` and `<s:a>` tags have an `anchor` attribute. Personally this seems like something you'd want to use Ajax/JS for, though.

Comment: I guess there are 1337 ways of doing this, and all of them are `too broad` to be described in an answer from scratch. You can use anchor on URL mapping the id of an object in the page, you can use javascript when loading the page, or AJAX / JS that you CAN use unless you have to finish this in two hours, returning a JSP snippet or JSON, you can set the new value in an Action property and read the property in the new page, both in javascript or in parameterized result configuration... try isolating your real problem by editing the question. And maybe show some code...

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I can think of right away is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.hash = "fieldset-<s:text name="latestIdOfFieldSet" />";
</script>
```

If you can figure out what's gonna be `latestIdOfFieldSet` before you render your jsp and set it in your action method. you should get what you are trying to do.